# How to sort an array without losing reference to the index thingy?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Okay. I'm effectively a -total- beginner to coding (taken some classes but a slow/dense learner) and the answer is probably ridiculously simple. I have one string array that has names and another that has the scores associated.

```
names[0] = blinky   
scores[0] = 42 (blinky's score)   
names[1] = inky   
scores[1] = 37 (inky's score)
```

in the for loop i calls the number (index number? I'm horrible with terms. The only thing that ever seems to make sense is the code itself). Anyway, I want to be able to preserve i.

I want to make a list that puts the names with the scores in order from highest to lowest.

I don't know if using util.Arrays or anything that will automatically sort will help. I believe I'll have to manually have to sort them in order to keep the names and numbers aligned

```
//Example  
String[] names = {"Blinky","Inky","Pinky","Clyde"};  
int[] scores = {42,37,67,50};  

for (int = 0; i < scores.length; i++){  
System.out.println("what do?")  
}
```

How would I go about making a list that puts the names in order? Simpler the better.
I'd be very appreciative of help.

Edit: I'd like to thank all of you for your help! :)

Comment: Are you able to sort scores alone, without names? If so your code will need small improvement, if no you better go to your book, because it is not easy topic to explain here.

Comment: I can sort them without the names. But I don't want to modify the original array.

Comment: What you want as result?

Comment: You should learn about algorithm... What you want: Sort by Score (base) what you need more: the index of score should map with the name for it (like the input). You have to think like: Solution 1: move the name like the Score when you sort (manual) Solution 2: Let it be an object with 2 field name and score, then you any Sort method, you always get what you want

Comment: any reason why you don't want to combine name and score into a single entity class? it'll be way less complicated to sort one entity than two separate arrays. With a class, it'll be more flexible - you can sort by name or by score, ascending or descending.

Comment: I simply want a high score list. top to bottom. 1st place - score. 2nd place - score. and so on.

Comment: One is a string and one is an array. also i didn't make a separate class. (I don't even know what "single entity" means in this context??) It's all one file. as illustrated above, I want "i" to still correspond to the names and scores. where it'll sort "i". (as per illustration it'd be 3 4 1 2 since those greatest to least)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the results below, you can try out the following codes.

```
Unsorted
---------
Blinky, score=42
Inky, score=37
Pinky, score=67
Clyde, score=50
sort by score ascending
Inky, score=37
Blinky, score=42
Clyde, score=50
Pinky, score=67 
sort by Name ascending 
Blinky, score=42
Clyde, score=50
Inky, score=37
Pinky, score=67
```

1) create a new class called NameScoreEntity to store both variables together (this way when you sort, both the names and scores are done at the same time)

```
public class NameScoreEntity {
    String name;
    int score;

    public NameScoreEntity(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ", score=" + score;
    }
}
```

2) you then create an arrayList of your new class to copy your two arrays into.

```
    String[] names = {"Blinky","Inky","Pinky","Clyde"};
    int[] scores = {42,37,67,50};

    List<NameScoreEntity> data = new ArrayList<>(); // your data is now stored here

    for (int i= 0; i < scores.length; i++){
        data.add(new NameScoreEntity(names[i], scores[i]));
    }
    //print unsorted
    System.out.println("Unsorted\n---------");
    for (NameScoreEntity e : data) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

3) finally, you just use the sort() method that is available in the list to do your sorting.

```
    System.out.println("sort by score ascending");
    data.sort(new Comparator<NameScoreEntity>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(NameScoreEntity o1, NameScoreEntity o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.score, o2.score); //for descending just swap o1 & o2
        }
    });
    for (NameScoreEntity e : data) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    System.out.println("sort by Name ascending");
    data.sort(new Comparator<NameScoreEntity>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(NameScoreEntity o1, NameScoreEntity o2) {
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name) ;//for descending just swap o1 & o2
        }
    });
    for (NameScoreEntity e : data) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a `TreeMap`, which will always keep the orders between your scores and match the corresponding `String`.

```
// new TreeMap that sorts from highest to lowest
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Then just `put` all your values into the `Map` using the loop you already have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
        map.put(scores[i], names[i]);
```

And finally you can just print the `Map`:

```
System.out.println(map);
```

Result:

> {67=Pinky, 50=Clyde, 42=Blinky, 37=Inky}